# What is the right keyboard configuration for my keyboard?

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard-layout, input-languages

I've got the greater than and less than symbols below the Esc key, and I don't know what the is the right keyboard configuration/language for it:

[image]

Comment: The fact that its got arabic keys may be a giveaway. What sort of laptop? Where did you buy this?

Comment: Dell Inspiron 13z 5323, Dubai. But I don't write arabic :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it. You have to add an additional input method. If you select in the Lanuage menu in the Control Panel "US English Table for IBM Arabic 238_L" you will notice it works.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an english/arabic layout - its referred to as keyboard layout 253 on [IBM's website](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/globalization/topics/keyboards/registry_index.html). I suspect the UAE -> US keyboard should work correctly. I touchtype so I just tend to set it to a standard layout and ignore the differences myself, but that *should* work

Comment: I can't find "English (UAE)" in the language menu

Comment: My bad Arabic(UAE) and US under that

Comment: I don't have US as option :S I chose "arabic (uae)" and when I go to "add a keyboard" I can see Persian, Urdu, Central Kurdish, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You have to press shift with ',و and shift with •.ز

[image]